# Use Java dialect in drools rules with mule

Tags: java, spring, mule, drools

I am trying to develop an application using `mule 4.1.1` and `drools 7.29.0`. The problem is that the rules compile only when I declare the dialect as "`mvel`". If, I try to run the rules with java dialect I am getting the following error:

```
Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='test-rule']
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (1:0) : The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (1:0) : The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (2:30) : Only a type can be imported. com.mycompany.model.Type resolves to a package
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (2:68) : Only a type can be imported. java.time.LocalDateTime resolves to a package
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (2:99) : Only a type can be imported. com.mycompany.model.Sequence resolves to a package
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (2:164) : Only a type can be imported. java.time.Instant resolves to a package
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (2:189) : Only a type can be imported. java.time.ZoneId resolves to a package
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (2:213) : Only a type can be imported. org.drools.core.spi.KnowledgeHelper resolves to a package
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (3:263) : Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (6:388) : KnowledgeHelper cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (6:413) : com.mycompany.model.Sequence cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (6:457) : org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (6:513) : com.mycompany.model.Sequence cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (6:558) : org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (6:624) : java.lang.Exception cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (6:646) : org.kie.api.runtime.rule.RuleContext cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (7:706) : LocalDateTime cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (8:788) : LocalDateTime cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (9:868) : LocalDateTime cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (10:998) : LocalDateTime cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (11:1126) : LocalDateTime cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (12:1211) : System.out cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (13:1274) : System.out cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (14:1336) : System.out cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (15:1396) : System.out cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (18:1545) : System.out cannot be resolved to a type
    rules/Rule_test$u45$rule1817291490.java (20:1634) : System.out cannot be resolved to a type
```

Does anyone know which could be the problem?

Comment: Add code snippet to your question

Comment: Add the code of test-rule

Comment: Please show how Drools is being called from your Mule application. Does it uses the Java Module? Or uses a custom Module?